# Download error on http://www.pagetemplates.org/: timed out -- Some packages may not be found

Tags: python, pyramid

does anyone knows what's happeing with:

[pagetemplates.org](http://www.pagetemplates.org)

I am creating a project, and downloading from that repository fails.
It looks like it's out of order for few days already.
I think it's have to do something with Pyramid, but I don't know how to turn it off - to skip downloading that part, or at least how to limit attempts for downloading as right now it keeps running in the loop?

Download error on http://www.pagetemplates.org/: timed out -- Some packages may not be found!

Is there a way to skip this, are thee some setting in some config file? I am trying to locate it in past hour but to avail.

Comment: Have you seen this workaround: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pylons-devel/oWGNF6vtCck/QEbRL__y_zcJ

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't word for me as there are almost 50 diffrent web locations that files are downloaded from, and I don't have list of them - if I aply that solution from google groups, then lots of errors are generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Siddharth Toshniwal, the problem has been discussed on the [pyramid mailing-list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pylons-devel/oWGNF6vtCck/QEbRL__y_zcJ).

Python has two package installation system : easy_install and pip. easy_install is the one used when you call `python setup.py develop`, and fetches the package directly from its website, while pip fetches from the python packages index.

So, while pagetemplates.org (which is the site for the package chameleon) is down, it won't be possible to install chameleon using easy_install, but it should work perfectly with pip. All you need to do is run `pip install chameleon` then resume what you were doing.

Comment: Actually that was the first thing I did, but it didn't help at all.
Although pip install chameleon installed it, it didn't prevent errors I described above.

Comment: That's strange, it worked for me. Could you show the full error log ?

Answer (score 3):

You can limit how `easy_install` searches for mirrors by using `easy_install --allow-hosts 'pypi.python.org' pyramid` for example. It's unfortunate that setuptools doesn't default to searching only the official pypi mirrors but I imagine it's due to the feature being introduced before there were official mirrors.